# SQL Count with multiple conditions then join

Tags: sql

Quick one,

I have a table, with the following structure

```
id  lid  taken
1   1    0
1   1    0
1   1    1
1   1    1
1   2    1
```

Pretty simply so far right?

I need to query the taken/available from the lid of 1, which should return

```
taken  available
2      2
```

**I know I can simply do two counts and join them, but is there a more proficient way of doing this rather than two separate queries?**

I was looking at the following type of format, but I can not for the life of me get it executed in SQL...

```
SELECT
   COUNT(case taken=1) AS taken, 
   COUNT(case taken=0) AS available FROM table
WHERE 
   lid=1
```

Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is correct just needs juggling a bit:

```
SELECT
   SUM(case taken WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS taken, 
   SUM(case taken WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS available FROM table
WHERE 
   lid=1
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
SELECT
   SUM(taken) AS taken, 
   COUNT(id) - SUM(taken) AS available 
FROM table
WHERE 
   lid=1
```

Comment: Your top query returns 4 and 4, you're just counting the rows each time

Comment: Just spotted that thanks, meant to be SUM not COUNT for first example :)

Comment: That second query just made me punch myself in the throat. I guess I kind of forgot about SUM.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT taken, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table
WHERE lid = 1
GROUP BY taken
```

This will return two rows:

```
taken  count
0      2
1      2
```

Each count corresponds to how many times that particular `taken` value was seen.

Comment: Different way all together, great SQL skills :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   SUM(case WHEN taken=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS taken, 
   SUM(case WHEN taken=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS available 
FROM table
WHERE lid=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird application of CTE's:

```
WITH lid AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT lid FROM taken
        )
, tak AS (
        SELECT lid,taken , COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM taken t0
        GROUP BY lid,taken
        )
SELECT l.lid
, COALESCE(a0.cnt, 0) AS available
, COALESCE(a1.cnt, 0) AS taken
FROM lid l
LEFT JOIN tak a0 ON a0.lid=l.lid AND a0.taken = 0
LEFT JOIN tak a1 ON a1.lid=l.lid AND a1.taken = 1
WHERE l.lid=1
        ;
```

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain. The query works and gives the expected result. It might differ from what you expect, but that is no reason to reject it.